# How can We use Flatbuffers Library in C# for xml Webservices?

Tags: flatbuffers

We are using XML Web Services for Android and Iphone Application. Now we want to optimize those WS to speedup the Mobile phone application performance.

Thanks

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with XML Web Services, but FlatBuffers simply produces and consumes binary byte arrays, so as long as XML Web Services can encode those, it should work.

That said, FlatBuffers is all about speed, and you will throw a lot of that away by going through a layer of XML. If you truly wanted to have a fast and optimized communication between your server and your apps, you would send a FlatBuffer directly, either over HTTP if that is simplest, or better yet directly over TCP/IP (or any minimal transport layer on top of TCP/IP).

Sending it directly might actually be simpler too, since you won't have to deal with XML at all.